# top: failed tty get in linux

Tags: unix

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo """"""""
now=`date "+%m/%d/%y:%H:%M:%S"`
echo -e "\n\n $now  ---CPU/MEM output--- \n\n"
cat /proc/cpuinfo
echo -e "\n\n"
cat /proc/meminfo
echo -e "\n\n"
echo `ulimit -a`
now=`date "+%m/%d/%y:%H:%M:%S"`
echo -e "\n\n $now  ---top output--- \n\n"
export TERM=xterm
top -n 1 -U username
top -H -n 1 -U username
echo -e "\n END OF Script"
```

Tried using

```
export Term
```

still getting error as failed to get TTY.
Please advice.

Comment: How are you running the script? The error has nothing to do with environment variables, it means that stdin/stdout are not connected to a terminal.

Comment: I ran the script using the crontab expression, this scripts needs to be run for every hour

Comment: Use the `-b` option to run `top` in batch mode, then it doesn't need a terminal.

Comment: I see it's giving different result using -b :top -b -H -n 1 -U username.

Comment: The question would probably be more appropriate at [unix.se].

Comment: And you really meant `export TERM` didn't you? Good luck, but yes, [unix.se] is more appropriate for this Q. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.